# Conditionally remove new lines in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have the following data:

```
{
 foo,
 bar,
 qux,
 zuu,
 sdf,
 sdfasdf
}
{
 abc,
 efg,
 hij,
 klm,
 nop,
 qrs
}
```

What I want to do is to convert them into blocks of one line and comma separated:

```
 foo,bar,qux,zuu,sdf,sdfasdf
 abc,efg,hij,klm,nop,qrs
```

What's the best unix shell programming way to do that?

I am trying to process JSON data like the following:

```
  {
   "Items": [
    {
        "A": {
            "S": "http://"
        }, 
        "B": {
            "N": "1"
        }, 
        "C": {
            "N": "0"
        }, 
        "D": {
            "N": "0"
        }, 
        "E": {
            "S": "2110221641826713463977"
        }, 
        "F": {
            "N": "2.5"
        }, 
        "G": {
            "S": " "
        }, 
        "H": {
            "B": "IA"
        }, 
        "I": {
            "N": "0"
        }, 
        "J": {
            "N": "0"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "A": {
            "S": "http://"
        }, 
        "B": {
            "N": "0"
        }, 
        "C": {
            "N": "1"
        }, 
        "D": {
            "N": "2"
        }, 
        "E": {
            "S": "67"
        }, 
        "F": {
            "N": "0"
        }, 
        "G": {
            "S": " "
        }, 
        "H": {
            "B": "Agh"
        }, 
        "I": {
            "N": "9"
        }, 
        "J": {
            "N": "1"
        }
    },     
  ]
 }
```

I am using JQ to parse this as below:

```
  jq -r '.Items[]'  | jq -r '{(.A.S): [.A.S, .B.B, .C.N, .D.S, .E.N, .F.N, .G.N, .H.N, .I.S]}'
```

This while parses the JSON but leaves data like above.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, actually processing JSON or JSONS input? In that case, use a JSON(S) processor.

Comment: Yes, i am actually processing JSON. I am using jq. Could not find a good way to accomplish this using JQ. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$ jq -c '.Items[]|[.[][]]' test.json
["http://","1","0","0","2110221641826713463977","2.5"," ","IA","0","0"]
["http://","0","1","2","67","0"," ","Agh","9","1"]
```

Comment: Or simply `jq -c '.Items[]|[.[][]]' test.json` :)

Comment: @konsolebox: I have seen `jq` for first time today. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Using `gnu awk` it can be done in a single command:

```
gawk -v RS='\n?[{}]\n?' 'NF{gsub(/ *\n */, ""); print}' file
 foo,bar,qux,zuu,sdf,sdfasdf
 abc,efg,hij,klm,nop,qrs
```

Comment: This worked for me. Still will wait for a bit longer just in case someone could help with this just using JQ.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tr` and `sed`:

```
tr -d '\n' < file | sed -r 's@\{ @@g; s@, @,@g; s@}@\n@g'
```

Output:

```
foo,bar,qux,zuu,sdf,sdfasdf
abc,efg,hij,klm,nop,qrs
```

Here's also a form that only uses `sed`:

```
sed -n '$!{ H; b; }; g; s|\n||g; s|{ ||g; s|, |,|g; s|}|\n|g; p' file
```

Comment: cat abcd | sed -n '$!{ H; b; }; g; s|\n||g; s|{ ||g; s|, |,|g; s|}|\n|g; p'

sed: 1: "$!{ H; b; }; g; s|\n||g ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)

I am getting an error with both the command lines above..

Comment: @user1328995 Try quoting `{` and `}` as `[{]` and `[}]` respectively. Do that only at the `s` commands.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk '!/^[{}]/ {printf "%s"(/,$/?"":RS),$1}' file
foo,bar,qux,zuu,sdf,sdfasdf
abc,efg,hij,klm,nop,qrs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sed` method also

```
sed ':loop ;N; /\n\}$/{P;d;t} ;/^{/{D} ;s/ *\(.*\)\n /\1/g ;t loop' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS=} '{$1=$1; gsub(/[{ ]/,"")} $0' file
foo,bar,qux,zuu,sdf,sdfasdf
abc,efg,hij,klm,nop,qrs
```